# How to aggregrate data created in the last hour in Go using MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, go, time, aggregate, mgo

I want to aggregate the distance field created in the last hour.

The error I get is is: `"missing type in composite literal"`

My code:

```
var lastHour = time.Now()
var hour=lastHour.Hour()-1
pipeline := []bson.M{
    {"$match": bson.M{"createdAt":{"$gt":hour} }},
    {"$group":
    bson.M{"_id": "",
    "total distance": bson.M{ "$sum": "$distance" },
    "maximum distance": bson.M{ "$max": "$distance" },
    "minimum distance": bson.M{ "$min": "$distance" },
        },
    },
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take a minute to review [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It will help you get a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

### First your error message

This [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) is invalid:

```
[]bson.M{
    {"$match": bson.M{"createdAt":{"$gt":hour} }},
    ...
```

More specifically this part:

```
bson.M{"createdAt":{"$gt":hour} }
```

Because the [`bson.M`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#M) type is:

```
type M map[string]interface{}
```

So a `bson.M` literal is effecively a map literal, where if the type of the value (in the key-value pairs) is not identical to the map type's value type, you have to explicitly write it out. This is mentioned in the spec:

> Within a composite literal of array, slice, or map type `T`, elements or map keys that are themselves composite literals may elide the respective literal type if it is identical to the element or key type of `T`.

The key-value pair: `"createdAt: {"$gt":hour}`, the value here is another `bson.M` value, but you did not mention it. The value type of this map is `interface{}`, so the compiler cannot guess you want it to be another `bson.M`. You have to spell it out for the compiler.

The correct version is:

```
bson.M{"createdAt": bson.M{"$gt":hour}}
```

This fixes the compile-time error, but won't give you the desired result.

### Now on to the task you want to achieve

If the `createdAt` field is a [`Date`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date) type in MongoDB, then pass a value of [`time.Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) when filtering by it.

Regarding the value of the passed `time.Time`, calculate the time value 1 hour ago (from the current time). For that, you may use the [`time.Add()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Add) method, which adds a given [`time.Duration`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) value to a time, and returns the new time. The duration may be negative to go back in time.

This is how it could look like:

```
anHourAgo := time.Now().Add(-time.Hour)
pipeline := []bson.M{
    {"$match": bson.M{"createdAt": bson.M{"$gt": anHourAgo}}},
    {"$group": bson.M{
        "_id":              "",
        "total distance":   bson.M{"$sum": "$distance"},
        "maximum distance": bson.M{"$max": "$distance"},
        "minimum distance": bson.M{"$min": "$distance"},
    }},
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you so much. Above code works well without any errors but I'm not getting the data from the database, output []. Below is the sample data. {
   "latitude" : -78.703347,
  "longitude": 32.710459,
        "date":ISODate("2017-11-29T19:58:00.389Z"),
 "distance" : 2500
},
{
   "latitude" : -78.703347,
  "longitude": 32.710459,
        "date":ISODate("2017-11-29T19:58:20.389Z"),
 "distance" : 250
}                When the above code is executed the output should be total distance : 2750.

Comment: @ShahulH Because in your MongoDB there is no `createdAt` field, only `date`. Either use `date` in the query, or rename the field to `createdAt` in MongoDB.

Comment: Thank you. I understood now.